# Postgresql Converting text to timestamp

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a database with an text type column called `cit_viol_time` which has an integer in each row.  I'd like to convert this integer to a timestamp somehow.

I've tried the following:

`select cit_viol_time::time(0) from table limit 1` where "table" is my table name

When I execute it in Navicat I get the following error:

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "838"`

Am I trying to cast this text incorrectly?  If so, how can I cast it to an actual timestamp i.e. 15:44

I'm reading the PG manual on casting but I think I'm missing something here.

**Update**
I've made the mistake of casting as time so I'm trying the following instead:

`SELECT  to_timestamp(cit_viol_time, 'HH24:MI') from tablename limit 1;`

This seems to work but it gives me an odd format of time.

`0001-03-08 02:00:00-05:50:36 BC`

All I'm trying to pull out is HH:MM in 24hour format which is what I thought I was doing with `HH24:MI`.

Comment: Which timestamp should `838` represent? And if you want a `timestamp` why are you casting to a `time`?

Comment: agree with @a_horse_with_no_name. postgres documntation is clear about   type convertion -  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: You're right, I should be using to_timestamp. I'll update my question with what I've just tried.

Comment: I don't understand why `838` should be `15:44`. What unit is the value 838 supposed to be? I can't be minutes, and it can't be seconds. And if it's supposed to be a time than indeed the data type `time` is more appropriate because `timestamp` also contains a date which I can't image how that as well could be "encoded" in the value 838. Can you explain the logic behind the conversion of 838 into 15:44?

Answer (score 0):

SO from your question it is not clear which actual value field `cit_viol_time` contains.

As it is referenced as "time" I can assume it could be either

- EPOCH time defined as "the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 local time". For more info see [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) If this is the case, to use `to_timestamp` function you need to know "date" part as well or have it available in some other field in the table.
- otherwise, integer value represents time in some uncommon time units such as minutes. In this case for example 838 would represent 838 minutes past midnight and therefore some math needs to be applied to get result

  ```
  int(838/60) = 13 hours
  mod(838,60) = 58 min`
  ```

  So in psql this would be:

  ```
  postgres=# SELECT INTERVAL '1 minutes'*cit_viol_time AS time 
             FROM (select 838 as cit_viol_time) tbl; 
     time   
  ----------
   13:58:00
  (1 row)
  ```